# Is it possible the opposite of tunneling?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, reflection, scattering, quantum-tunneling

In tunneling we have particles of energies $E<V$ going through barriers of potential $V$. Can we get particles of energies $E>V$ get reflected by these barriers of smaller potentials?

Comment: You can solve the Schrodinger equation for this particular case in order to evaluate the reflection coefficient.

Comment: There is always some portion that is reflected [google](http://www.physics.brocku.ca/PPLATO/h-flap/phys11_1.html)